# Command-line-based capacitance decoding

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I am an amateur programmer and have just written a simple Capacitor Identifier mostly to practice. I have not had many people review my coding and thought this would be a good time to start. It is completed and works. Is there a better way I should have went about it? What should I look at in what and how I am writing that might improve my approach?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

# Get the arguments list 
cmdargs = sys.argv

cmdargs = cmdargs[1:]

tolerances = {'B':'.10%','C':'.25%','D':'.5%','E':'.5%','F':'1%','G':'2%','H':'3%','J':'5%','K':'10%','M':'20%','N':'.05%','P':'+100% to 0%','Z':'+80% to -20%'}

# Get the total number of args passed
total = len(cmdargs)

# Templete String for output
capTemp = '{} = {}'

# output container
result = []

# cycle through passed arguments and decode each capacitor
for arg in cmdargs:
    case = len(arg)

    if(case == 2):
        temp = arg + ' pf, ' + str(float(arg) / 1000000) + 'uf'
        result.append(capTemp.format(arg, temp))
    elif(case == 3):
        cap = int(arg[:2]) * 10**int(arg[2:])
        temp = str(cap) + ' pf, ' + str(float(cap) / 1000000) + 'uf'
        result.append(capTemp.format(arg, temp))

    elif(case == 4):
        cap = int(arg[:2]) * 10**int(arg[2:3])
        temp = str(cap) + ' pf, ' + str(float(cap) / 1000000) + 'uf, ' + tolerances[arg[3:].upper()] + ' tolerance'
        result.append(capTemp.format(arg, temp))


# print the decoded capacitor values
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Variable usage

Assign `cmdargs` once, and get it right the first time.  Put a more insightful comment there.  Rename it to `cmd_args` for readability.

```
# Skip argv[0], which is the name of this program
cmd_args = sys.argv[1:]
```

The `total` variable is never used.

The variable name `case` is not descriptive enough.  Naming a variable `temp` is almost always a bad idea as well.  I suggest names like `arg_len` and `decoded_value`, respectively.

`tolerances` is a constant, and should be named `TOLERANCES` [by convention](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants).  Format it using one entry per line for readability.

### Decoding technique

It is good practice to separate your calculations from your output routines.  Start by defining a function `decode_capacitance(code)`:

```
def decode_capacitance(code):
    '''
    Decodes the capacitance as a (value, tolerance) pair.
    The value is a float representing the nominal number of picofarads.
    The tolerance is a free-form string, and may be None.
    '''
    code_length = len(code)
    if code_length == 2:
        return float(code), None
    elif code_length == 3:
        return float(code[:2]) * 10 ** int(arg[2:]), None
    elif code_length == 4:
        return float(code[:2]) * 10 ** int(arg[2:3]), TOLERANCES[code[3:].upper()]
```

In Python, it is idiomatic to write `if` conditions without parentheses.

However, there is a lot of redundancy there, and not much insight either.  An improvement would be:

```
def decode_capacitance(code):
    '''(Same docstring)'''
    base_pF, scale, tol = float(code[0:2]), int(code[2:3] or 0), code[3:4]
    multiplier = 10 ** scale
    return base_pF * multiplier, TOLERANCES.get(tol.upper())
```

You fail to [interpret the third digit properly](http://www.wikihow.com/Read-a-Capacitor).  If the third digit is `8` or `9`, it is supposed to be interpreted as a multiplier of 0.01 or 0.1, respectively.  To fix that, change the middle line to:

```
    multiplier = 10 ** (scale if scale <= 5 else scale - 10)
```

As @vnp noted, you have no validation or error handling (and I haven't added any for you).

### Formatting technique

Define another function to display the capacitance and tolerance in the desired format.

It would be nice, I think, to automatically select the most natural units.

The standard symbol for the farad is `F` — a capital letter.

### Putting it all together

With the appropriate functions defined, the main loop is quite simple.  Print results as you go; there's no need to store `results`.

```
import sys

TOLERANCES = {
    'B': '.10%',
    'C': '.25%',
    'D': '.5%',
    'E': '.5%',
    'F': '1%',
    'G': '2%',
    'H': '3%',
    'J': '5%',
    'K': '10%',
    'M': '20%',
    'N': '.05%',
    'P': '+100% to 0%',
    'Z': '+80% to -20%',
}

def decode_capacitance(code):
    '''
    Decodes the capacitance as a (value, tolerance) pair.
    The value is a float representing the nominal number of picofarads.
    The tolerance is a free-form string, and may be None.
    '''
    base_pF, scale, tol = float(code[0:2]), int(code[2:3] or 0), code[3:4]
    multiplier = 10 ** int(scale if scale <= 5 else scale - 10)
    return base_pF * multiplier, TOLERANCES.get(tol.upper())

def format_capacitance(pF, tolerance):
    if pF > 1000000:
        mantissa, unit = pF / 1000000, 'uF'
    else:
        mantissa, unit = pF, 'pF'

    output = '{} {}'.format(mantissa, unit)
    if tolerance is not None:
        output += ', ' + tolerance + ' tolerance'
    return output

# Skip argv[0], which is the name of this program
cmd_args = sys.argv[1:]

# Cycle through passed arguments and decode each capacitor
for arg in cmd_args:
    print('{} = {}'.format(arg, format_capacitance(*decode_capacitance(arg))))
```

Comment: I plan to add a error handling, a -h & --help arg to provide a help output, and a read me, i wanted to make a note of you as a contributor to the code, i also plan to study your points heavily, when i complete error handling and the help args, would it be correct to re-edit it or re-post it to get some idea if i am on the right track with it, also need to come up with a simple project to make use of your suggestion and practice them

Comment: For iterative reviews, please [post a separate question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357). (Thanks for asking about the process!)

Answer (score 3):

**Usage**

- The code expects a perfect input. A user making a honest mistake is faced with an exception trace. It is nice to detect an error early and print an error message *in big friendly letters*.
- In the same tune, I am not sure how the valid input should be formatted. It is very well possible that a professional radio engineer knows exactly what is expected; not many of us are though. The `usage()` function is pretty much a must.

**Structure**

- Any piece of code you care about should be written with a future reuse in mind. In a Python world it usually means that you'd be able to `import` it into another project. A habit of factoring the code into well defined functions is immensely helpful.

**Misc**

```
cmdargs = sys.argv
cmdargs = cmdargs[1:]
```

looks really strange. I'd go for

```
cmdargs = sys.argv[1:]
```

wrapped in a `try/except` clause of cource.

Comment: Concerning your last remark, an out-of-bounds list slice is just an empty list. No exception is raised.